# What percentage of iPhone users using each iOS version

Tags: iphone

I am looking for up-to-date report of iOS versions deployment in percentage. 
Something like [Chitikia Report](http://chitika.com/research/2010/ios-4-now-powering-50-of-iphone-traffic/) but up-to-date.

This info is extremely important for taking a decision of what iOS version to deploy my App...

Any idea where to find that? Is Apple publish such reports for its registered developers?

Many Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What percentage of iPhone users have the different versions of iPhone OS/firmware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021929/what-percentage-of-iphone-users-have-the-different-versions-of-iphone-os-firmware)

Answer (score 4):

Back from the dead :)

Finally Apple provides this information on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/).

Example screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might struggle to get these stats. As I understand it the latest Developer SDK T&C's prevent analytics software from collecting this sort of data. I know Flurry no longer collects
the iOS version (its just displayed as 'Unidentified' now).

I've never seen any data published by Apple to developers either.

Comment: There's no information in Google Analytics either... AFAIK you can just tell iPhones from iPod touches. I'm not sure where iPads go in even...